# Deleting Entire rows where Range Selection is blank (Without looping)

Tags: excel, vba, delete-row

As the title says, It seems obvious but I can't seem to find a **one-liner** to it **without looping**. Is there a method able to do this task with a fast execution time ?

Here is my failed attempt (It crashes my excel file) :

```
Worksheets("Iso_Journal").Range("A:P").EntireRow.SpecialCells(xlBlanks).EntireRow.Delete
```

Any knowledge would be appreciated !

**Edit:**

Found this method but it filters instead of deleting (much faster), it does the job but it still not what I truly need

```
Worksheets("Iso_Journal").Range("A:P").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="<>"
```

**Edit 2:** (Response to @FaneDuru)

[image]

Comment: Does it raise an error related to `overlapping selections`? Do you want deleting **all empty ROWS**, or **all rows of All EMPTY CELLS**?

Comment: That's exactly the error I get + excel file not responding for a few seconds

Comment: I wanna delete ALL rows where ALL cells in my selection range are ALL empty

Comment: Please try `Worksheets("Iso_Journal").Range("A:A").SpecialCells(xlBlanks).EntireRow.Delete`

Comment: It works but my excel file was 'Not Responding' for 20 seconds ... I noticed that it added 1048576 blank rows that's why it bugs

Comment: Amma retry it with a specified column range instead of whole columns, maybe that's the source of problem

Comment: When I use Range("A" & 1 & ":P" & lastrow) I get the overlapping error again

Comment: Then, try `Dim wsJ As Worksheet` `Set wsJ = Worksheets("Iso_Journal")` followed by `wsJ.Range("A1:A" & wsj.Range("A" & wsJ.rows.count).End(xlup).row).SpecialCells(xlBlanks).EntireRow.Delete`

Comment: Why using more columns? An empty row **has all columns cell empty**...

Comment: It works but it's hella slow & produces the problem that I added to my OP Edit 2. But still thanks a bunch my man !

Comment: How large is the range in terms of rows and how many empty rows do you estimate to exist/be processed?

Comment: Not huge, 2400 rows in total & 250 empty rows. PS: Don't hesitate to formulate an answer so I can validate yours, you already helped enough

Comment: It is not a huge range... Are there formulas in the respective workbook, being affected by these deletions? I mean, relative cells to be updated after deletion... Try `Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual` before the deletion code line and see how long it takes.

Comment: I think I found the line that creates 1XXXXX empty rows, it's the following : Worksheets("Iso_Journal").Range("A:P").Value = Worksheets("Journal_Modified2").Range("O:AD").Value

Comment: What does/did `wsj.Range("A" & wsJ.rows.count).End(xlup).row` returns in Immediate Window? When you suspect such a case (a space in a cell at the very bottom) you can double click on the bottom line of the empty cell bellow the range you think it is. It should bring you on the problematic cell. Or change the column: `wsJ.Range("A1:A" & wsj.Range("B" & wsJ.rows.count).End(xlup).row).SpecialCells(xlBlanks).EntireRow.Delete`.

Comment: Where is the code you show in your comment? Is it following the one deleting rows? I thought you found a cell at the very bottom of the sheet (in A:A)...

Comment: Actually, your first simple one-liner works just fine & fast [ Dim wsJ As Worksheet
    Set wsJ = Worksheets("Iso_Journal_OS") ]. The code I've shown in previous comment is what added a lot of empty/unnecessary rows (To answer ur question, it is located before the 'Empty rows suppression' code)

Comment: Please make any answer so I can validate it & thanks my man !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please, try the next adapted code. If the target is to delete all empty ROWS, it is enough to use a single column. And also to limit the number of rows to be processed:

```
Dim wsJ As Worksheet 

Set wsJ = Worksheets("Iso_Journal")
wsJ.Range("A1:A" & wsj.Range("A" & wsJ.rows.count).End(xlup).row).SpecialCells(xlBlanks).EntireRow.Delete
```

If the range to be processed is huge, and the workbook contains many formulas, you can make the code a little faster placing `Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual` before the deletion line, followed by `Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic`. Even if the rows are deleted in block, Excel needs to update the formulas row by row, and no good to calculate after each...